# Can a complex positive definite matrix be a unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

According to [Orthogonal, symmetric and positive definite matrices!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825146/orthogonal-symmetric-and-positive-definite-matrices), identity matrix is the only (real) positive definite matrix which is also orthogonal.

However, is it possible to find a complex matrix which is positive definite and unitary?

To clarify, when I say positive definite, I talk about Hermitian matrices only.

Comment: The eigenvalues of such a matrix would all be positive, and all have absolute value $1$.

Comment: Yes. When I say positive definite, I talk about Hermitian matrices only.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That's a pretty substantial hint. Why not put it in an answer post?